# java.time.Instant - error while parsing a huge date

Tags: java, java-time, java.time.instant

I'm trying to parse a really large date (but still way less than Instant.MAX) using the Instant.parse method but getting an error.

```
String input = "78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(input);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2106)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:2008)
at java.base/java.time.Instant.parse(Instant.java:399)
```

The BC date "-78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z" is parsed ok.

Did I find a bug in Java :)?

Comment: no, not a bug - as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)), `parse()` is using ISO-8601; and it [requires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years): "*To represent years before 0000 or after 9999, the standard also permits the expansion of the year representation  ... An expanded year representation [±YYYYY] ..., and it must be prefixed with a + or − sign*" - posted input string is missing the `+` sign

Comment: "_Did I find a bug in Java_" Anytime you ask this question, almost always the answer is NO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Feature, not a bug

No, it is not a bug - is working as specified!

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) of `parse()`:

> is parsed using [DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

and from [ISO_INSTANT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

> returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 instant format

`ISO_INSTANT` refers to `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` to `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` to [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE). The last one says:

> - Four digits or more for the year. Years in the range 0000 to 9999
>   will be pre-padded by zero to ensure four digits. Years outside that
>   range will have a prefixed positive or negative symbol.

This is meant to imply that years to be parsed must abide by the mentioned format too.

Finally, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for ISO-8601 ([Years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years)):

> To represent years before 0000 or after 9999, the standard also permits the expansion of the year representation .... An expanded year representation [±YYYYY] must have an agreed-upon number of extra year digits beyond the four-digit minimum, and **it must be prefixed with a + or − sign**.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

---

The input string `"78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z"` is missing that `+` sign, while `"-78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z"` correctly starts with a `-` sign.

The input `"+78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z"` is parsed without error.

---

Hint: you can *check* the format by formatting a test date/time/... before parsing.
For example:

```
var test = Instant.from(OffsetDateTime.of(78000000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,ZoneOffset.UTC));
System.out.println(test.toString());  // or using any relevant formatter
```

Output:

> `+78000000-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Thank you @user16320675, it's clear now. BTW, I wonder why it was decided not to allow a "+" for dates within the 0000..9999 range (say "+1300-01-01T00:00:00Z" is unparseable), from my point it would make more sense. But it is what it is.